# Replace blank spaces in repeating JOIN() with "no contact"

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I want the spaces between the semi-colons that indicate no number was found to be replaced with "no contact".

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substitute()`, like this:

`=if( $A38 = $A37, substitute( join("; ", I38, J37), " ; ", " no contact; " ), I38 )`